# Saving image out of Google app

Tags: google

I can't find a way to get an option to save an image out of the Google app on my phone? I open the image and after going through enough many steps to call it awful UX, I get to these menu options which offers sharing but not saving:

[image]

Is it purposely designed to make saving images difficult or impossible?

Comment: By "Google" app, did you mean Google search? If it's, then you have to open its website first on the browser, then you should be possible to save it from browser (e.g. by long-pressing the image)

Comment: Do you know what the reasoning is behind such awful UX ? Why didn't they design it to make that function more easily accessible?

Comment: Yes , Google search app